# LESS - button:hover does not work

Tags: html, css, less

On hovering a button I want to display a hidden element. It does not work, what is wrong?

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovspB)**

LESS

```
button{
 color: red;

 &:hover{
   h1{
     display: block;
   }
 }
}

h1{
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<button> hover me </button>

<h1> you are hovering </h1>
```

Comment: You've nested the H1 inside the button in your LESS/CSS but not in the HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your LESS is compiling to `button:hover h1` - in other words, an `<h1>` that is a *child* of a hovered button.

Try `&~h1` instead of just `h1`. This will make it work for siblings. [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxahC)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
button{
  color: red;
  &:hover + h1{

      display: block;

  }
}

    h1{
      display: none;
    }
```